# How to read in XML from web service and query rowset attributes in C#?

Tags: c#, xml, web-services, xsd

Here is the sample XML that I am receiving from the web service.

```
<xml xmlns:s='uuid:BDC6E3F0-6DA3-11d1-A2A3-00AA00C14882'
xmlns:dt='uuid:C2F41010-65B3-11d1-A29F-00AA00C14882'
xmlns:rs='urn:schemas-microsoft-com:rowset'
xmlns:z='#RowsetSchema'>
<s:Schema id='RowsetSchema'>
<s:ElementType name='row' content='eltOnly'>
    <s:AttributeType name='NAME' rs:number='1'>
        <s:datatype dt:type='string' rs:dbtype='str' dt:maxLength='25'
         rs:maybenull='false'/>
    </s:AttributeType>
    <s:AttributeType name='DESCRIPTION' rs:number='2' rs:nullable='true'
         rs:writeunknown='true'>
        <s:datatype dt:type='string' rs:dbtype='str' dt:maxLength='80'/>
    </s:AttributeType>
    <s:extends type='rs:rowbase'/>
</s:ElementType>
</s:Schema>
<rs:data>
<z:row NAME='JOE BLOW' DESCRIPTION='PROGRAMMER'/>
<z:row NAME='ANN SMITH' DESCRIPTION='FRONT DESK'/>
<z:row NAME='STEVE JOHNSON' DESCRIPTION='TESTER'/>
</rs:data>
</xml>
```

I'm not sure how to go about getting to the `<rs:data>` node. I eventually want to enumerate through each `<z:row>` and get the attributes `NAME` and `DESCRPTION`. The webservice returns this to me as a string so I load the string into an XMLDocument like this:

```
XmlDocument xDoc = new XmlDocument();
xDoc.LoadXml(xmlString);
```

Now, I'm not sure if I need to use a `XmlNamespaceManager` in order to tel my `xDoc` to import the `<s:Schema>`

I've tried to select a single node with an XPath with no luck because of the prefix rs.

```
XmlNode xNode = xDoc.SelectSingleNode("/rs:data");
```

If there is any further information needed, please ask.

Comment: FYI, the language is "C#", not "C Sharp".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are taking the xml as a string try parsing it like instead of using Load()

```
var xml = XDocument.Parse(xmlstring);
```

You have to use the namespace to get hold of the data properly.

```
XNamespace ns = "#RowsetSchema";

foreach (var element in xml.Descendants().Elements(ns + "row"))
{
    Console.WriteLine ("Name = " + element.Attribute("NAME").Value + ", " + "Description = " + element.Attribute("DESCRIPTION").Value); 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's some classes for handling your xml, using these extensions: http://searisen.com/xmllib/extensions.wiki

```
public class Test
{
    XElement self;
    public Test(XElement self)
    {
        this.self = self;
    }

    public RSDataRow[] DataRows
    {
        get
        {
            if (null == _DataRows)
            {
                _DataRows = self.GetEnumerable("rs:data/z:row", xrow => new RSDataRow(xrow)).ToArray();
            }
            return _DataRows;
        }
    }
    RSDataRow[] _DataRows;
}

[DebuggerDisplay("{Name}")]
public class RSDataRow
{
    XElement self;
    public RSDataRow(XElement self)
    {
        this.self = self;
    }

    public string Name
    {
        get { return self.Get("NAME", string.Empty); }
    }

    public string Description
    {
        get { return self.Get("DESCRIPTION", string.Empty); }
    }
}
```

You use it like:

```
Test test = new Test(XElement.Parse(xmlstring));
foreach (RSDataRow row in test.DataRows)
{
    string name = row.Name;
    string desc = row.Description;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using xml with linq it can be done like this:

```
XDocument xmlDoc = new XDocument();
xmlDoc = XDocument.Parse(xml);

XNamespace ns = "#RowsetSchema";

var namesDescs = from namesDesc in xmlDoc.Descendants().Elements(ns + "row")
    select new
    {
       name = namesDesc.Attribute("NAME").Value,
       description = namesDesc.Attribute("DESCRIPTION").Value,
    };
```

Comment: near total copy of Flowerking's post

Comment: @ChuckSavage: I realise that but was just wanting to show a solution using linq so in that sense its slightly differn't but I voted his answer up and corrected it.